# How std::strong_ordering works only with zero?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, visual-c++-2019

I am just researching a [three-way comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) operator `<=>`. I see that it returns `std::strong_ordering`. However, I fail to understand how the compiler is restricting only `0` in comparison operators (`so<0`, but not `so<1`)

```
#include<compare>
int main()
{
  std::strong_ordering so = 55 <=> 10;

  so < 0; // Fine
  so < 1; // Fails
}
```

Similarly, `so>20` won't work either. Following also won't work:

```
constexpr int Zero = 0;
so == Zero; // Error
so == 0; // Fine
```

**EDIT** - Interesting observation (on MSVC compiler). Following is valid:

`so < nullptr`

Comment: What's your question? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering) says: _"Comparison operators are defined between values of this type and literal ​0"_

Comment: [Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering): "The behavior of a program that attempts to compare a strong_ordering with anything other than the integer literal ​0​ is undefined."

Comment: My question is not about UB, but about error reported by compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using anything but a literal `0` to compare against `std::strong_ordering` is explicit undefined behavior, see [[cmp.categories.pre]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/cmp#categories.pre-3) of the C++20 draft.

It is up to the compiler/standard library how or whether this is enforced/diagnosed.

One way of achieving a diagnostic for the UB without any compiler magic is to use `std::nullptr_t` as argument to the overloaded comparison operator of `std::strong_ordering` (which has unspecified type according to the standard). Any integral zero literal can be implicitly converted to `std::nullptr_t`, but literals with other values or constant expressions that are not literals, cannot. See [[conv.ptr]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1).

This is also mentioned in a draft note as possibility.

Libc++ seems to instead use a member pointer to some hidden class, see [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/7c3769df62c0b3820130aa868397a80a042e0232/include/compare#L80).

Libstdc++ seems to do something similar, using a hidden class type that needs to be constructed from a pointer to itself, see [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/compare#L59).

However neither of these implementations diagnose all arguments that result in UB according to the standard. In particular all of them also accept `nullptr` as argument without diagnostic: https://godbolt.org/z/esnvqR

I suppose full diagnosis of all the cases would require some compiler magic.

Comment: Alright! I see VC++ having `using _Literal_zero = decltype(nullptr);`, and expecting `_Literal_zero` to be another argument of the overloaded operator. And hence, only `0` as constant or `nullptr`  (!) can be passed.